# Dynamic JQuery UI slider constructed from HTML5 data-* and CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to create multiple jquery UI sliders using a single CSS `class` and HTML5 `data-*` values, but without success. I can get some values, but some simply doesn't work.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/FTtAb/1/

As you can see, `data-id` and `data-val` works but I can't get values for `data-min`, `data-max`, `data-step`(which are the most important already). Try to uncomment these lines and see what's happen.

So, my question; is there a way to get these values using `data-*` or something else?

Comment: Your example is working for me : sliders works, callback too to update the slider value... What is not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from parseInt you should also use the `data` function. Here is a modified fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FTtAb/3/

```
jQuery('.sliderui').each(function() {
    var obj = jQuery(this);
    var sId   = "#" + obj.data('id');
    var val   = parseInt(obj.data('val'));
    var min   = parseInt(obj.data('min'));
    var max   = parseInt(obj.data('max'));
    var step  = parseInt(obj.data('step'));


    obj.slider({
        value: val,
        min: min,
        max: max,
        step: step,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            jQuery(sId).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `data()` can make this more readable indeed. On the other hand, you should always specify the radix you want `parseInt()` to use, otherwise you can get strange results or even errors depending on the `data-` attribute value (e.g. `042` will be parsed as `34` instead of `42`).

Comment: Look so simple now. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The values you extract from your `data-` attributes are strings, not numbers. The [min](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-min), [max](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max) and [step](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step) options of the jQuery UI [slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) widget only take numbers.

You can use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert these values to numbers:

```
var min   = parseInt(jQuery('#' + id).attr('data-min'), 10);
var max   = parseInt(jQuery('#' + id).attr('data-max'), 10);
var step  = parseInt(jQuery('#' + id).attr('data-step'), 10);
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FTtAb/2/).

(As an aside, consider caching the result of `jQuery('#' + id)` in a local variable for efficiency).